# How to get file attributes in ColdFusion 7?

Tags: coldfusion

I cannot find a function that tells me the attributes of a given file. I specifically need to get the file's size. How do I find this info.?

edit:

I think I found an answer, just not the answer I was hoping for:

> So far till ColdFusion 7, there was no
>   good way to find information like
>   size, last modified date etc about a
>   file. Only way you could do that was
>   to use cfdirectory tag to list the
>   directory, get the query from it, loop
>   over the query until you hit the
>   desired file and then fetch the
>   required metadata.
>   http://coldfused.blogspot.com/2007/07/new-file-io-in-coldfusion-8-part-ii.html

Anyone know of a better way?

Answer (score 9):

I believe cfdirectory is your simplest answer - but note, you can use the filter attribute as your filename, and you won't have to loop over the result.

Comment: I'd add this code example to your answer for extra awesome: <cfdirectory action="list" filter="myfile.txt" name="fileCheck"/><cfoutput>#fileCheck.size#</cfoutput>

Answer (score 4):

```
<cffunction name="getFileSize">
    <cfargument name="filepath">

    <cfreturn createObject("java","java.io.File").init(Arguments.filepath).length()>

</cffunction>
```

Comment: I got gibberish...

code:

<html>
<head>
<title>A ColdFusion Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<cffunction name="getFileSize">
    <cfargument name="filepath">

    <cfreturn createObject("java","java.io.File").init(Arguments.filepath).length()>

</cffunction>

<cfset filePath = "C:\richard\anthony\sampleFile.txt">
<cfset getFileSize(filePath)>
<cfoutput> sampleFile.txt is this big: #getFileSize#</cfoutput>

output:

sampleFile.txt is this big: cftest2ecfm1841964723$funcGETFILESIZE@167b9d4

Answer (score 2):

The [CFLib FileSysLibrary](http://www.cflib.org/library/FileSysLib) has a bunch of file functions.

- [FileSize](http://www.cflib.org/udf/fileSize)
- [FileSizeCOM](http://www.cflib.org/udf/FileSizeCom)

May be of particular interest

Comment: The above library has (as of Oct 2012) 63 functions.

Comment: Did you click on the link under 'few' or 'functions'? That links to two specifically that would help.